# Is there any way to configure multiple registries in a single package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, artifactory, package.json

Is there any way the I can define two registries in **publishConfig** in *package.json*?

the use case is for publishing the artifact in 2 different location based on the purpose, when it is a SNAPSHOT it will use the snapshot path and for release purpose it uses the other one.

something like:

```
"publishConfig": {
        "snapshot-registry": "http://artifactory.test/artifactory/api/npm-snapshots"
        "release-registry": "http://artifactory.test/artifactory/api/npm-releases"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

By reading the npm package json docs [npm-package-json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig) You can only override existing `npm-config` settings by using `publishConfig`, so you may not be able to add new properties.

However, you can use `.npmrc` to set different registry entries for scoped packages and default. In the `.npmrc` example bellow I have the snapshot package set for the GitHub registry and everything else may be published to the default npm registry.

```
@snapshot:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/snapshot
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

The tricky part is which registry will the package go to. right? with the settings we have now, a simple `npm publish` would not work or it may just publish to the default registry. One approach I use, is login to my scoped registry with `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=snapshot`, edit my package.json to match the name of my scoped package, for example `@snapshot/package` so it does not go to the default registry then publish.

Then, you may login to the default registry, edit accordingly and publish again there.

I hope this helps you, Its an annoying process, we may even need a "package registry manager" Don't know if one exists.